# hibernate max record from table with the an additional criteria

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to fetch the record from table where highest age + the name

```
  Criteria criteria = session
 .createCriteria(Person.class)
 .setProjection(Projections.max("age"));
 Integer maxAge = (Integer)criteria.uniqueResult();
```

This above code gives me the highest age in the whole table , Whereas i want to get the highest age only where person name = "john"

how can i achieve this ?

I tried to add a critera afterwards in this way

```
 Criteria critNew = session
 .createCriteria(Person.class);
 critNew.add(Restrictions.eq("personName","john"));
 critNew.add(Restrictions.eq("age", maxAge));
```

but with this way it will only search for john where maxAge is "the highest age in the whole table"

for example if maxAge in the whole table is 50.
and there are 3 person with the name "john"  with ages "10", "20" , "30"
My Code will not work

Please suggest 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put together into one criteria.

```
Criteria criteria = session
   .createCriteria(Person.class)
   .add( Restrictions.eq("name", "john"))
   .setProjection(Projections.max("age"));

Integer maxAge = (Integer)criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: thanks , but with this way , the result will be fine but my criteria return an integer (the highest number) . When i try to put it in the list i.e List list = criteria.list();   list= 46(the highest number) where as i am looking for the complete Person Class ,  Any Idea..

Comment: Change the last line `List maxaeges = (List)criteria.list();`